# Adding icon with submenu items

Tags: android

I have made submenu with some items in it. Now I want to add different icon with submenu items. I have also applied the code to the menu items for adding icon but it is not showing me icons my code is this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMEnu(Menu m) {
    SubMenu s1 = m.addSubMenu("menu1");
    s1.add(0,0,1,"1").setIcon(R.drawable.icon1);
    s1.add(0,1,2,"2").setIcon(R.drawable.icon2);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(m);
}
```

Comment: so did you receive any error ??

Comment: no m not getting an error its working fine except showing me icon with my items.

Answer (score 5):

Submenus don't support icons.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html:

> Icon Menu
>       This is the collection of items initially visible at the bottom of the screen at the press of the MENU key. It supports a maximum of six
>   menu items. THESE ARE the only menu items that support icons and the
>   only menu items that do not support checkboxes or radio buttons.

Comment: >>sub-menus don't support icons. That is not nice :-(

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [list of the standard icons](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#menuapx)  . I don't see a "settings" icon. Perhaps you mean "Preferences" (ic_menu_preferences)?

You can set the icon programmatically like this:

```
menu.add(0, MENU_QUIT, 0, "Quit").setIcon(R.drawable.menu_quit_icon);
```

You can also set it in your xml layout like this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/save_button"
  android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
  android:title="Save Image"/>
```

-- [Creating Menus in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Comment: i have done the same thing as u have also seen but when i m executing it is not showing me icons with my menu items

Comment: thanks it worked,  when adding menu if you set the icon it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu m) {
SubMenu s1 = m.addSubMenu("menu1");
s1.add(0,0,1,"1");
s1.add(0,1,2,"2");

MenuItem menuItem = s1.getItem(0);
menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.icon1);
MenuItem menuItem1 = s1.getItem(1);
menuItem1.setIcon(R.drawable.icon2);

return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(m);
}
```