# Icon is not set on submenu

Tags: java, android, android-menu

I had made a sub menu in android and I wanted to add icon on sub-menu but it does not display.
I have written the following snippet of code:

```
    int base = Menu.FIRST;

    SubMenu sm = menu.addSubMenu(base, base + 1, Menu.NONE, "submenu");
    MenuItem item1 = sm.add(base, base + 2, base + 2, "sub item1");

    sm.add(base, base + 3, base + 3, "sub item2").setIcon(R.drawable.block_user);
    sm.add(base, base + 4, base + 4, "sub item3").setIcon(R.drawable.extendedaway);
    item1.setIcon(R.drawable.away);
    sm.setIcon(R.drawable.chaty);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think icons are supported for submenus. Have a search here in SO, here for example: [adding icon with submenu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634171/adding-icon-with-submenu-items)

See this tutorial: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

> **Options Menu**
>
> This is the primary set of menu items for an Activity. It
>   is revealed by pressing the device MENU key. Within the Options Menu
>   are two groups of menu items:
>
> Icon Menu This is the collection of
>   items initially visible at the bottom of the screen at the press of
>   the MENU key. It supports a maximum of six menu items. These are the
>   only menu items that support icons and the only menu items that do not
>   support checkboxes or radio buttons.
>
> Expanded Menu This is a vertical
>   list of items exposed by the "More" menu item from the Icon Menu. It
>   exists only when the Icon Menu becomes over-loaded and is comprised of
>   the sixth Option Menu item and the rest.

It's a bit dated but I don't think it has changed.